# SQL Server Scalar - Value Function

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Why does the below Scalar function return: `*`

```
Create FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_Get_Minute_Hour]
    (
      @dtStartDate DATETIME ,
      @dtEndDate DATETIME
    )
RETURNS VARCHAR
AS
    BEGIN  
        DECLARE @DiffSecs INT ,
            @Result VARCHAR(100) 

        SET @DiffSecs = DATEDIFF(SECOND, @dtStartDate, @dtEndDate)

        SELECT  @Result = CAST(( ( @DiffSecs % 86400 ) / 3600 ) AS VARCHAR(2))
                + ':'
                + CAST(( ( ( @DiffSecs % 86400 ) % 3600 ) / 60 ) AS VARCHAR(2)) 

        RETURN @Result
    END
```

Above function return output like *
 Expected Output : - MM:HH

Comment: What is Expected Output

Comment: @JaydipJ  Function return in output difference between two date minute and hour

Comment: TT. suggestion is correct use `RETURNS VARCHAR(6)` OR `RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)`

Comment: @TT  Use both varchar(6) and varchar(MAX) but not working

Comment: @TT I check function with your updated answer but not working

Comment: So in what context are you checking this result? In SSMS? In your program? Could be that the formatting in the program you are displaying the result in is wrong.

Comment: @TT Thank you , It's working fine

Comment: You can help me by accepting my answer (check the checkmark at the top left of my answer)

Answer (score 0):

Possibly because `VARCHAR` is the equivalent of `VARCHAR(1)` and is just one character long. Change the return of the FUNCTION to `RETURNS VARCHAR(16)` (or the maximum size you expect).

Your FUNCTION should look like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_Get_Minute_Hour]
    (
      @dtStartDate DATETIME ,
      @dtEndDate DATETIME
    )
RETURNS VARCHAR(16)
AS
    BEGIN  
        DECLARE @DiffSecs INT ,
            @Result VARCHAR(100) 

        SET @DiffSecs = DATEDIFF(SECOND, @dtStartDate, @dtEndDate)
        DECLARE @sign BIT = CASE WHEN @DiffSecs<0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
        SET @DiffSecs=ABS(@DiffSecs)

        SELECT  @Result = 
                CASE WHEN @sign=1 THEN '-' ELSE '' END
                + CAST(( ( @DiffSecs % 86400 ) / 3600 ) AS VARCHAR(4))
                + ':'
                + CAST(( ( ( @DiffSecs % 86400 ) % 3600 ) / 60 ) AS VARCHAR(4)) 

        RETURN @Result
    END
```

Tested this with:

```
DECLARE @dtEndDate DATETIME=GETDATE();
DECLARE @dtStartDate DATETIME=DATEADD(MINUTE,13,DATEADD(HOUR,6,DATEADD(DAY,-1,GETDATE())));
SELECT dbo.[fn_Get_Minute_Hour](@dtStartDate,@dtEndDate);
```

Result

```
17:47
```

Comment: @HitendraDeriya By maximum you mean `RETURNS VARCHAR(5)`?

Comment: Yes , I use varchar(MAX)